# Three recurrence relations of orthogonal polynomial, monic and orthonormal polynomial

Tags: recurrence-relations, orthogonal-polynomials

1. $\{p_n\}$ is orthogonal polynomial which satisfies

$$p_{n+1} = (A_n x +B_n) p_n +D_n p_{n-1}$$

2. whose monic form $\tilde{p}_n$ satisfies

$$x \tilde{p}_n(x) = \tilde{p}_{n+1}(x) + b_n \tilde{p}_n(x) + d_n \tilde{p}_{n-1}(x),$$

3. whose orthonormal form $\hat{p}_n$ satisfies

$$x \hat{p}_n(x) = E_n \hat{p}_{n+1} + F_n \hat{p}_n(x) + E_{n-1} \hat{p}_{n-1}(x).$$

Now the problem is how to get the other two from one? What's the relation
among the coefficients?

Comment: Orthonormal in what sense?Are $A_n,B_n,D_n,b_n,d_n$ real numbers? Are $b_n,d_n$ the same as $B_n$ and $D_n?$ What is a monic form?

Comment: Basically, try being more specific. This question has no context that lets us determine what any of it means.

Comment: More specifically than Thomas Andrews, what is your definition of "orthogonal" and "orthnormal"? I.e. Which of the many possible inner products on polynomials are you using? Also, are these real polynomials, complex polynomials, polynomials over some other field? Is there some reason you sometimes refer to them as $p_n(x)$ and other times as just $p_n$, even in the same equation?